# How to handle this merge issue in GIT

Tags: linux, git, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I am having a situation here. I did some commit to master branch and after move these commit to
other branch x using and

```
     git cherry-pick
```

and I run git cherry-pick on x branch itself. Now after this git cherry-pick, forgot to run git push command.

Almost at same time my colleague did the git cherry-pick for his commits and did the git push.

When I see the git log on his machine I couldn't find my commit and realize that I forgot to run git push.

I went to my machine, did the git push. But I am seeing this message now

Comment: please add the output of `git log --graph --decorate --oneline HEAD @{u}`, after doing a `git fetch`.

Comment: your `git push` should have failed as your colleague changed your upstream by his push. (assuming you both were working on the same branch.)

Comment: Yes @michas ,we both are working on same branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a better log output it is hard to tell, what happend.

I guess you both had the same base commit, each of you did a cherry-pick, and you merged both cherry-picks in order to be able to push it.

The log above shows one commit from you (cf5b726), one commit from your colleague (1aa2ecd) and a merge (28529d0) of the first two commits, which seems to originate from a `git pull`.

And yes, the merge carries the changes of both merged commits. - After all that's exactly the point of a merge. ;)

Comment: Thanks @michas for your response ,You're right merger(28529d0) is result of "git pull".Can we use this merger(28529d0) id an input to somewhere else where we want both the changes to be reflected?

Comment: sure, the merge commit is just an ordinary commit. You can use it wherever you need a commit. You can use `git pull --rebase` to avoid those merge commits in future. Maybe a look at `gitk` might help you understand what is going on.

Comment: Fine @michas ,you mean to say we should use git pull -rebase instead of git pull.Also ,I'm thinking commit id "1aa2ecd" is also  having changes of cf5b726?

Comment: Please add a more detailed output as suggested by my first comment on your question. Without this it is impossible to tell whether 1aa2ecd contains cf5b726. - (`gitk` also shows this information.)

Comment: Thanks @michas ,Once I have gitk output available,will post it here.

Comment: I have added the git log --graph output as EDIT to my question,Would you help me reading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git log --graph` or `git log --format=raw` (or magit for Emacs) to see the parents of a commit.